Annoying geese on the roof
I live in an elderly facility in Gahanna Ohio. Geese land on the flat roof every evening. I’m on the fourth floor and it’s very loud from 6:30 PM till about 8 Or 9 PM. How can the manager of this facility stop them from landing on the roof? It is very annoying, and it cuts into my sleep.

The things I can think of, such as spreading wire netting over the roof, might harm the geese.  What I would do in your place is contact the local Audobon Society to ask for their advice.

From 6 to 9 in the evening cutting into your sleep? Or did you mean to write till 9 AM?

@Willeke I am decades away from living in an elderly facility, but I am normally fast asleep long before 9 and would be irritated if I was kept up until then with regularity.

@KateGregory, there is a big difference in having noise around the time you go to bed and noise through the night. The solutions offered might differ. I am an early awake person, alarm at 5:30 but for me noise stopping around 8 PM would not clash with sleep. Noise till 8 AM would. So asking confirmation is within reason.

Try having a large small cat, like a Maine Coon, hang around the house.

I found a site on Google called Bird Barrier*.   The site specifically discusses geese, and offers these compelling reasons (which might get the attention of the owners of the OP's residence) for keeping geese off their roof.

(1) A single adult goose can produce up to 2 pounds of excrement each
day.
(2)  Nesting geese are very protective and can be aggressive to people
who get near their nesting area, eggs, or goslings.
(3) Bird  excrement  can clog gutters, contaminate standing water,
and cause  damage to the  exterior surfaces of buildings.
(4) Geese feed on  some roofing materials and can cause severe damage
and leaks.

The full article gives the pros and cons of Gridwire, but warns that Gridwire can be used on the roof only if geese have not aready started nesting on the roof.  The site also discusses Visual Deterrents and something called Optical Gel, and recommends starting with one of these.  It has a contact link for a harrassed owner to describe his specific problem and get advice.  This is obviously a commercial company, but please note:
I am in no way affiliated with Bird Barrier, own no stock in BB, and have never used it.

Geese are very annoying, that is definitely true. However people have limited options when it comes to controlling what they do. For example, there are multiple small office buildings in the Greater Toronto Area with signs like "warning, do not use this door, the geese are attacking people, please go around to that other door".
Preventing geese from landing somewhere would be incredibly expensive if you wanted to put something all over the roof that they didn't like -- and I have no idea what might work. Perhaps making them a space they would prefer? Building a large pond on the grounds, surrounded by plenty of grass (geese love grass which is why cottagers replacing their woodlands with lawn to the lake upset their neighbours) would entice them off the roof and onto the pond? Though they might not be any quieter there.
If your wish is that they not see the property where you live as a valid stopping point on their way north, I truly don't think that is within a person or company's abilities. It should be temporary, and your peace will return.

These days many geese have taken to staying put and not migrating. Non-migratory populations extend across most of the lower 48 states, and non-migratory birds now outnumber the migratory population. Overall population has increased by more than a factor of 4 since 1970.
